# Ipywidget dropdown menu to select figure from list

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I have a list of csv files from `glob.glob`. Each csv is used to generate a figure. I would like to use an ipywidget dropdown menu so that only the file that is selected is plotted.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.html.widgets import interactive

csvs = sorted(glob.glob('*/*csv'))
for csv in csvs:
    df = pd.read_csv(x, sep=',')
    plt.figure()
    df.plot()
```

The dropdown menu would therefore be

```
w = widgets.Select(options=csvs)
display(w)
```

It would also be ok to use `widgets.Button` if this is the only way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it

```
import glob
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.html.widgets import interactive

csvs = sorted(glob.glob('*/*csv'))

def plot(x=csvs[0]):
    dfs = pd.read_csv(x, sep=',')
    dfs.plot(figsize=(12, 8))

w = widgets.Select(options=csvs)
interactive(plot, x=w)
```

Now does anyone know why the widget isnt kept when I export the notebook to html?